# Converting Char "1" to hex "4'h0001"

Tags: string, system-verilog

I am trying to convert a string to the same value in hex. Eg

If string="abc123" it's hex value should also be 24'habc123.
The length of string is 64 and so I convert each char to hex,I'll get 64*4=256 bits of hex value

eg if text_o_cplus.getc(i)=a i.e 97,I should assign it a hex value a i'e 4'ha;
But I am not getting proper way to do that. That's what I tried

```
      int j=255;
      for(int i=text_o_cplus.len();i>0;i--)
      begin
       while(j>=0)
         begin   
            case(text_o_cplus.getc(i))

            48:     begin
                     rev_result[j]=4'b0000;
                     j=j-4; 
                     break;
                     end

   and so on.
```

rev_result is defined as

```
       bit [64][4] rev_result;
```

I tried to define it as

```
       bit [255:0] rev_result
```

also but it didn't work.

Can someone please suggest how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in function:

```
   bit [255:0] rev_result = text_o_cplus.atohex();
```

Comment: I don't want the hex value of  a string "x". I have a string lets says"abc",                                                                       
 I want to convert "a" to 4''b1010 or 4'ha                                                                                            "b " to 4'hb and "c" to 4'hc.

Comment: Read the LRM. `atohex()` does exactly what you want.